# ¿Cómo visualizar un pdf en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf

La función de agregar PDF´s si funciona y se aloja en la dirección:
public_html\storage\app\public\cv ya tengo PDF´s listos para visualizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es que menciona que la ruta no la encuentra.

[image: Error NotFoundException]

Aqui van las rutas con los métodos POST y GET

web.php

```
Route::post('deleteSolicitudes', 'UnetePageController@deleteSolicitudes')->name('deleteSolicitudes');
Route::get('public/{cv}', 'UnetePageController@show')->name('CvUnete')->middleware('auth');
```

UnetePageController.php

```
public function indexSolicitudes()
    {
        $promotor = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','promotor')->get();
        $reclutador = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','reclutador')->get();
        $recepcionista = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','recepcionista')->get();
        $soporte = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','soporte')->get();
        $control = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','control')->get();
        $beneficios = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','beneficios')->get();
        $cv = SolicitudesTable::where('tipo','cv')->get();
        return view('admin/unete/solicitudes')
                    ->with('promotor', $promotor)
                    ->with('reclutador', $reclutador)
                    ->with('recepcionista', $recepcionista)
                    ->with('soporte', $soporte)
                    ->with('control', $control)
                    ->with('beneficios',$beneficios)
                    ->with('cv',$cv);
    }

public function show($id)
    {
        $solicitudes = SolicitudesTable::find($id);
        $url = Storage::get($solicitudes->cv);
        return redirect($url);
    }


 public function deleteSolicitudes(Request $request)
    {
        SolicitudesTable::destroy($request->id);
        return back()->with('info',"Borrado");
    }
```

solicitudes.blade.php

```
  {{---Botón de ver ---}}
  <a href="{{url($promotor[$i]->cv)}}" target="_blank">
       <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  {{---Botón de eliminar ---}}
  </td>
  <td>{{$promotor[$i]->comentarios}}</td>
  <th scope="row"><a class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" href="#" onclick="borrar({{$promotor[$i]->id}})"></a></th>
```

Aqui esta la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿el problema consiste en que la ruta del PDF no funciona correctamente?

Comment: Así es, quizá esta algo mal pero no encuentro el error, la ruta, o el error quizá esté en solicitudes.blade.php al querer llamar abrir el pdf desde un href.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas te indico que en la documentación de Laravel utiliza el response te dejo por aqui el enlace a la documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-responses

Un ejemplo básico sería este:

```
$filename = 'test.pdf';
$path = storage_path($filename);

return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
 'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
]);
```

Comment: Ese es el punto, que no debe ser básico, el que necesito tiene que ser dinámico, extraer los datos desde la base de datos. Pero gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

no encuentra la ruta porque tu ruta `Route::get('public/{cv}..` esta pidiendo como parametro el cv, pero en la vista de la imagen que subiste tu tienes como url esto:

```
public/cv/{nombre.pdf}
```

tienes mal la ruta, deberia ser asi :

```
Route::get('public/cv/{file}...
```

igual puedes ver con dd() en tu metodo show y ver que te trae el parametro $id=  (dd($id);)
otra opcion para ver las rutas en la terminal es: `php artisan route:list -c`